# Ошибка в командной строке компьютера "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package". Я скачал jupyter notebook и он не открыв

Tags: python

Команды которые я использовал:pip install notebook,jupyter notebook
[image: После скачивания я попытался открыть файл, введя скопированную команду с официального сайта jupyter.Так же я добавил файл jupyter.py в path(jupyter notebook не смог найти даже с консольной командой "show jupyter notebook". По возможности сделайте если не сложно по шаговую инструкцию. Использовал обновлённый pip при скачивании. )]

Comment: 1. [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 2. [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)